# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)x^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Why if $x <1$ then, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)x^{n}<\infty$

I know that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}=\frac{1}{1-x}<\infty$

Comment: So multiply the entire series by $x$ and then integrate term by term.

Comment: Do you know how to find the radius of convergence of a power series?

Comment: For $$\;x=-3<1\;,\;\;\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)x^n\;\;\text{does not converge}\ldots$$ So I am guessing you didn't *actually* mean "for$\;x<1\;$", but in fact...

Comment: How did you prove that $\sum x^n$ converges when $|x| < 1$?  Similar techniques will work here.  There are more powerful tools, such as the ratio text, but if you knew those, I don;t think you would be asking the question.

Comment: False. The series diverges if $x\le-1.$